# How do I make stdin a tty?

Tags: ruby, linux, unix, tty, pty

There are programs which change their output depending on whether their stdout is a tty. So if you put these in a pipeline, or redirect them, the output is different than it would be in your shell. Here is an example:

```
$ touch a b c

# when running ls alone, it places them on one line
$ ls
a b c

# when stdout is not a tty, it places them on their own line
$ ls > output

$ cat output
a
b
c
output
```

So, if I want to show someone what a command like this should look like (e.g. I'm writing a tutorial), I have to highlight and copy the output from the terminal and then save it to a file.

It seems like I should be able to do something like this:

```
ls | ttypipe > output
```

Where `ttypipe` is a hypothetical program whose stdin (and hence ls's stdout) responds with true when asked if it's a tty.

I know that in Ruby, I can do something like this:

```
require 'pty'         # => true
IO.pipe.map(&:tty?)   # => [false, false]
PTY.open.map(&:tty?)  # => [true, true]
```

But that's for a child process, and not the current process, so as a result:

```
$stdin.tty?  # => false
```

I could exec, I can't think of a way to have that affect the stdin file descriptor.

Comment: `$stdin.tty?` (requiring nothing, using IO#tty?) returns `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write `ttypipe` because a pipe is a pipe, and can never be a tty. However, you can write a `ttyexec` with slightly different syntax:

```
ttyexec ls > output
```

It would open a pseudo-terminal, run `ls` in it, and copy anything `ls` writes to the terminal to `ttyexec`'s stdout.

Lo and behold, there's a tool like this already: `script`. It opens a program in a new, hidden pty to log interactions with it, but we can ignore the logging part and just use its terminal opening properties:

```
$ touch a b c

$ ls
a  b  c

$ script -q -c 'ls' /dev/null > output

$ cat output 
a  b  c  output
```

Comment: Thanks. That's how I wound up implementing it https://github.com/JoshCheek/dotfiles/compare/84a7b01c58aa3ee3ba8a93f9199c1375e3671894...10f801b1e82205dcffd40a4f5c9402b857368929